# How can I have quick access the music controls?

Tags: indicator-sound

I'm coming back to Ubuntu and wow, a lot of things have changed since version 9. There is one thing that really annoys me. Back in the good old days where you can set up your desktop as you wanted, there was a tiny applet called music-applet so you can have the controls of the music player on the panel. So if you wanted to hear another song, just click the >> arrow and that was really easy.

Ubuntu 12.04 needs one click on volume indicator and then click con the NEXT arrow from the dropdown menu. I was wondering if there is a way to at least, just hover the volume indicator so the dropdown menu shows up and you click the next song arrow.

Maybe there are other ways to change songs quickly?

Comment: I've always used the dedicated buttons on my keyboard, or a keyboard shortcut if the music player is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to change behavior of the indicator, but you can use multimedia keys on your keyboard. If you don't have next/previous track buttons on your keyboard, you can bind other keys in the Keyboard System Settings. My keyboard only has volume up/down/mute buttons, but I have bound them to the next/prev/play buttons instead, as I don't use software volume control really. You can also keep both functions and use Ctrl+VolumeUp to mean next track, for example. You're free to decide what buttons or combination to bind, in the keyboard settings.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just mapped some keyboard shortcuts and it's working like a charm :)